# Reshape a pandas dataframe, flattening the data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe as shown in the following .

```
fips_txt    Stabr   area_name   Attribute   Value
9   1000    AL  Alabama Civilian_labor_force_2000   2133223.00
10  1000    AL  Alabama Employed_2000   2035594.00
11  1000    AL  Alabama Unemployed_2000 97629.00
12  1000    AL  Alabama Unemployment_rate_2000  4.60
13  1000    AL  Alabama Civilian_labor_force_2019   2241747.00
14  1000    AL  Alabama Employed_2019   2174483.00
15  1000    AL  Alabama Unemployed_2019 67264.00
16  1000    AL  Alabama Unemployment_rate_2019  3.00
17  1000    AL  Alabama Median_Household_Income_2019    51771.00
18  1000    AL  Alabama Med_HH_Income_Percent_of_State_Total_2019   100.00
```

I want to create a new dataframe with this as the following.

```
fips_text    Stabr    area_name    Civilian_labor_force_2000 Employed_2000   Unemployed_2000    ....    Med_HH_Income_Percent_of_State_Total_2019
1000    AL    Alabama    2133223    2035594    97629    ....    100
```

PS - There could be more columns for other states as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `unstack`:

```
df.set_index(['fips_txt', 'Stabr', 'area_name', 'Attribute']) \
  .unstack('Attribute') \
  .droplevel(0, axis=1) \
  .reset_index() \
  .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```